# sql max function usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

For example, I have a value in my table like below

```
Id  ExamType Value Date
1   IELTS     240  2019-01-01
2   IELTS     120  2018-12-01
3   TOELF     100  2017-12-12
4   TOELF      80  2019-01-20
5   GMAT      70   2016-01-01
```

and I want my query gives me max values of these exams like below

```
IELTS (2019) 240
TOELF (2017) 100
GMAT  (2016) 70
```

I wrote my query like below

```
SELECT x.ExamType,MAX(x.Value) 
FROM TableExam x  
GROUP BY x.ExamType
```

but this query did not give the result as same as that I wanted, so I need a query to get result like above,
thank for your help.

Comment: Hi Ally!  It might help if you edit the post to add what results you *are* getting from your query, that are different from what you want, so we can help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: you want the year as well?

Answer (score 4):

Looking to your sample seems you need  a join on the subquery for max value group ExampType

```
select m.ExamType, year(m.date), t.max_value value
from TableExam m 
INNER JOIN (
    select ExamType, max(value) max_value
    from TableExam
    group by ExampType
) t on t.max_value = m.value and t.ExamType = m.ExamType
```

Comment: Is there sth. wrong this code because it did not work

Comment: You have error ?.  show error message  .. wrong result?  show thw actual result  ..

Comment: just blank result

Comment: @scaisEdge Your query seems to be written for MySql but the question is tagged SQL Server.

Comment: the query is written for pure sql  ..avoiding specific db sintax

Comment: Yes, my bad of course sql server also has a YEAR() function, although I doubt it is part of standard sql

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  correct  ..  Year()  work for mysql and sqlserver but is  not a standard sql function  ..

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `DENSE_RANK()` ? :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExamType ORDER BY Value DESC) AS SEQ
      FROM TableExam t
     ) t
WHERE SEQ = 1;
```

If you have ties with `Value`  then you would use `DENSE_RANK()` instead.

Comment: ı am sorry but i can not understand your code because i can not find my output value in your code

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` window function

```
 with cte1 as
    ( select *,row_number()over (partition by ExamType   order by Value desc ) rn
     from TableExam
    ) select ExamType,year(date1) as Year, Value from cte1 where rn=1
    order by year(date1) dese
```

Using Subquery

```
   Select * from (Select *,row_number()over(partition by ExamType 
   order by Value desc) rn from TableExam ) a
   Where rn=1
   Order by date1 desc


ExamType    Year    value
IELTS      2019     240
TOELF      2017     100
GMAT       2016     70
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f157a226cef152c0d09331961151c13)

Comment: I am using sql-server 2012 and i tried like you wrote but this code did not give me max values on the contrary code giving me whole value in table

Comment: I believe OP does not want to group by date

Comment: @apomene how you believe i dont know but it seems to me he need that

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin you query will return multiple rows per EaxmType, something OP does not want

Comment: thanks but this code also can not work according to my output values

Comment: @Allytscnt https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f157a226cef152c0d09331961151c13 check this works fine

Comment: Thanks for your help I want to ask you another question I want to use this code in my other codes as snipped do you think that I can, I mean in a part of my query  ( can with cte notation avoid this kind of usage or not ) thanks

Comment: U can avoid cte no problem but accept it first I made it subquery version

Comment: Edited by using Subquery